# VlookUp according to ComboBox1 selection

Tags: excel, vba

I need some assistance please. I am using a userform with combobox1 to show all opened excel workbooks :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wkb As workbook
    With Me.ComboBox1
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            .AddItem wkb.Name
        Next wkb
    End With
End Sub
```

I have another macro run perfectly but I need to add a Vlookup step tovlookup some columns with another workbook which is the one I am suppose to chose from the combobox1

I used Macro record as I am not really good with it

```
Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],[COMBOBOX1 selection]Sheet1!C5:C6,2,FALSE)"
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F3")
    Range("F2:F3").Select
```

I am sure you can tell, its not working. Would you please assist?

Comment: Could this be an X/Y problem? Why would you want to pick a workbook name from a combobox? Would you know the name (or part of it) beforehand? Can you elaborate a little bit more on that.

Comment: The workbook that I need to vlookup with always start with LOB then a date. The reason I used comobox that some times the user will have several LOB files with different dates . So the needs to choose  right one.

Comment: No one can assist?